# Jest doesn`t mock(set spy) on needed function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

My test function **reverseAdd** call another function **add** that is defined in same module.
I need to test, if test function call another.

Module

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function reverseAdd(a, b) {
  add(b, a);
}

module.exports = {
  add,
  reverseAdd
}
```

Test

```
const exp = require('./add');

describe('add', () => {
  it('should add two numbers', () => {
    expect(exp.add(1, 2)).toBe(3);
  });

  it('should add two numbers', () => {
    exp.add = jest.fn();

    exp.reverseAdd();

    expect(exp.add).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Result

```
Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero
```

As I understand wraped function is another function, and it is not called in test function.

How can I wrap/spy the function **add**?

playground: https://repl.it/repls/WoodenElectricInstances

Comment: Check this issue, you can't mock `add` function in this way: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ltamajs, I found [solution](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-214939935).

Need to rewrite module to

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function reverseAdd(a, b) {
  module.exports.add(b, a); <----- here changes
}

module.exports = {
  add,
  reverseAdd
}
```